# My function not returning any result in python?

Tags: python, function, loops, return-value

so I was doing a little math study and decided to recreate a simple assignment in python which is to find the factor pairs of a number. I did that quite easily but now I have a little issue which I have tried to figure out but to no avail. Here's the code:

```
# Find the factor pairs of a given number

def getFactorPairs(n=0):
    num = n
    factors = []
    pair = None

    for p in range(1, num + 1):
        for r in range(1, num + 1):
            if p * r == num:
                pair = (p, r)
                if (r, p) not in factors:
                    factors.append(pair)
                else:
                    continue
    return factors

print(getFactorPairs(120)) # Works fine

getFactorPairs(120) # This doesn't give any result. Why?
```

When I use the `print(getFactorPairs())` and pass in a number, the result is as expected but when I just call the function `getFactorPairs()` and input a number, it doesn't give me any result. I will be glad if someone can show me where I am doing something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: did you try actually capturing the result? `result = getFactorPairs(120)` and then `print(result)`?

Comment: This is because the function `returns a value` but it does not `print` anything. The returned value can be stored in a variable but just calling the function is equivalent to writing a value and doing nothing

Comment: Oh I see! I just learnt something new. I have created a variable to capture the result. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
getFactorPairs(120) # This doesn't give any result. Why?
```

with

```
temp = getFactorPairs(120)
print(temp)
```

**The reason**

When a function return value/values it is not automatically displayed by python.

Answer (score 0):

The print function will display the values.
if you assign the result of the getFactorPairs() to a variable and display the variable using print it will display the result

```
def getFactorPairs(n=0):
    num = n
    factors = []
    pair = None

    for p in range(1, num + 1):
        for r in range(1, num + 1):
            if p * r == num:
                pair = (p, r)
                if (r, p) not in factors:
                    factors.append(pair)
                else:
                    continue
    return factors
result = getFactorPairs(120)
print(result)
```

You are simply executing the function without displaying the result

Comment: You are very welcome. Remember to mark as the answer if you are happy with it.